# Azure CLI az functionapp config appsettings - space in appsetting

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am using az functionapp config appsettings to automatically create my Azure Function settings.  One of my settings is a SQL connection string that has spaces in it.  The space in the connection string is causing issues loading because each appsetting is delimited by a space.

Can somebody tell me why this works

```
az functionapp config appsettings set --resource-group "Test" -n "rbasxxtest1" --settings Setting1='Test Value'
```

but this doesn't?

```
Setting1Value='Test Value'
az functionapp config appsettings set --resource-group "AzureOE" -n "rbasxxtest1" --settings Setting1=$Setting1Value
```

This is the error I get
he command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:

not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/util.py", line 244, in shell_safe_json_parse
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed double quotes

```
Setting1Value="Test Value"
echo SettingValue= $Setting1Value
az functionapp config appsettings set --resource-group "AzureOE" -n "rbasxxtest1" --settings Setting1="$Setting1Value"
```

Comment: It would be more helpful to explain why? Give a man a quote and he will be satisfied for a day. Show him how to quote, and he will never pester you again!

Comment: Very appreciate this answer you shared. Please mark this answer as solved thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works:-)

Answer (score 2):

Some additional notes for or those, who - like me - have multiple App-Settings inside one string variable in Git Bash, and at least one of those settings contains a space, double quoting alone does not work, unfortunately:

```sh
# This works:
az webapp config appsettings set --name x --resource-group y --subscription z --settings "ENV_ONE=Test Value" "Env_Two=Foobar"
# --> Success

# This does NOT work:
settings="\"ENV_ONE=Test Value\" \"Env_Two=Foobar\""
az webapp config appsettings set --name x --resource-group y --subscription z --settings $settings
# --> Error: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

That is apparently because of the way that bash handles the quotes, see

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively#quoting-issues and
https://github.com/fengzhou-msft/azure-cli/blob/ea149713de505fa0f8ae6bfa5d998e12fc8ff509/doc/use_cli_with_git_bash.md#quoting-issues

For me, the only thing that helped was putting the whole command in a string and then calling it with `eval`:

```
# This works:
settings="\"ENV_ONE=Test Value\" \"Env_Two=Foobar\""
eval "az webapp config appsettings set --name x --resource-group y --subscription z --settings $settings"
# --> Success!!
```